# What are the changes required to make oauth based authentication with mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-security

Hi I am new to mongodb and spring security.I am trying to create an token key basen authorisation for login the below is the link which I followed to create project set up:-
[Spring Security with in Memory allocation](http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/)

The following are the code changes I have made: -

1] Resource Server.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
        anonymous().disable()
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/user/**")
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

2] Authorization Server: -

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {


private static String REALM="MY_OAUTH_REALM";

@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Autowired
private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

    clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("my-trusted-client")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
        .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
        .secret("secret")
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120).//Access token is only valid for 2 minutes.
        refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);//Refresh token is only valid for 10 minutes.
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.realm(REALM+"/client");
}
```

}

3] Security Configuration: -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("ADMIN").and()
        .withUser("bob").password("abc123").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore){
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

}
```

4] Method Security: -

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2SecurityConfiguration securityConfig;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

5] Rest Controller: -

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorldRestController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;  //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work


    //-------------------Retrieve All Users--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        if(users.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    //-------------------Retrieve Single User--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        System.out.println("Fetching User with id " + id);
        User user = userService.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }



    //-------------------Create a User--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody User user, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
        System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getName());

        if (userService.isUserExist(user)) {
            System.out.println("A User with name " + user.getName() + " already exist");
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

        userService.saveUser(user);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/user/{id}").buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }


    //------------------- Update a User --------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println("Updating User " + id);

        User currentUser = userService.findById(id);

        if (currentUser==null) {
            System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        currentUser.setName(user.getName());
        currentUser.setAge(user.getAge());
        currentUser.setSalary(user.getSalary());

        userService.updateUser(currentUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(currentUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    //------------------- Delete a User --------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        System.out.println("Fetching & Deleting User with id " + id);

        User user = userService.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("Unable to delete. User with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        userService.deleteUserById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }


    //------------------- Delete All Users --------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> deleteAllUsers() {
        System.out.println("Deleting All Users");

        userService.deleteAllUsers();
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

}
```

what is the code change i need to make such that I can make login authentication using Mongdb document by name "user" instead of inmemory authentication.

Comment: you need only a mongodb based token store, which can be found in google...

Comment: ok can you suggest me any link which I can follow up for mongodb based token store?

Comment: https://github.com/iainporter/oauth2-provider/blob/master/src/main/java/com/porterhead/oauth2/mongodb/OAuth2RepositoryTokenStore.java

Comment: https://github.com/caelwinner/spring-security-mongo/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/caeldev/springsecuritymongo/MongoTokenStore.java

Comment: ton of them.. just google it..